# How to make string comparisons to be case insensitive on process / thread level?

Tags: c#, .net, string, globalization, cultureinfo

I'm reading about string comparison in C# and I wondered:

Can I predefine the compare info on a process / thread level to be case insensitive so I can use `==` directly when compare two strings?

Comment: That sounds like a well of confusion, create an extension that wraps string.Equals w/ CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

Comment: More importantly, be glad it can't be done. Can you imagine that libraries could change this kind of setting? That would lead to huge amounts of confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't.

The [`==`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#673) operator calls [`string.Equals`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#603), which on it's own, calls [`string.EqualsHelper`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#367).

As you can see, it doesn't use any culture or comparision settings (like the [`Equals(String value, StringComparison comparisonType)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#550) overload does). It just compares the string character by character.

You have to call an overload of `Equals` to get the result you want, which isn't the default behavior, and can't be changed, *unless* you have a way to override **every** `string` with an own implementation of `string.Equals` or the `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly BUT:

You could create an attribute using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) and apply it to all methods in your assembly.

I didn't use PostSharp for a long time so I can't provide you an example, but it can be done.

I don't like this idea and it might lead to lots of trouble in the future. But it is possible and close to what you've asked.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with it?